# CGI::Application::Plugin::REST Instance Script

Tags: perl, rest, cgi, cgi-application

I am attempting to build a Restful service with [CGI::Application::Plugin::REST](http://search.cpan.org/~jaldhar/CGI-Application-Plugin-REST-0.2/lib/CGI/Application/Plugin/REST.pm), but I am not sure how to actually structure the script. Is it the same as using CGI::Application so the below will be the Instance Script referencing modules withing the Perl library path?

```
    use CGI::Application::Plugin::REST qw( :all );

$self->rest_route(
        '/Stage/:id'    => {
            'GET'    => 'Stage',
        },
        '/Status/:id'   => {
            'GET'    => 'Status',
        },
        '/Metadate/:id' => {
            'GET'    => 'Metadata',
        },
$self->run();
```

I will admit I am probably learning CGI::Application backwards, and am looking for an easy way out as once the framework is done the rest is very achievable. Also I did not want to use MVC frameworks as I wanted to build it from scratch. Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you said you want to use this as a structure to build off of, I'd recommend putting your CGI::App logic in its own module. This will make it easier to test later when you start writing tests. Your App.pm will look like a normal CGI::App controller:

```
package App;

use strict;
use parent 'CGI::Application';
use CGI::Application::Plugin::REST ':all';

sub setup {
    my $self = shift;
    $self->rest_route(
        '/some/route' => {
            'GET' => 'read_widget',
            'POST' => 'save_widget',
        },
    );
}

sub read_widget { ... }
sub save_widget { ... }
1;
```

And then in your instance script that the web server will call, you can simply `use App; App->new->run;`

[You can find a fully functioning example in the C::A::P::REST test lib.](https://metacpan.org/source/JALDHAR/CGI-Application-Plugin-REST-0.2/t/lib/Test/CAPREST.pm)